# Custom route on Post with form. Rails 3.2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Just after awhile of browsing the stackoverflow was not able to find the solution for the following issue:

I have a scaffold model `fleets` and I would like to match route `\fleets\postponed?id=31\` to a specific action in the controller => `def postponed` with `POST` method.

While I tried to follow some of the tutorials, here where it failed:

`Couldn't find Fleet with id=postpone`

Here are my routes:

```
  match 'fleets/postponed.id?:id', :controller => "fleets", :action => "postponed", :via => :post
  resources :fleets
```

Here is the form for `POST` method:

```
 <%= form_for @fleet, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }, :url => { :id => @fleet.id }  do |f| %>
   blah-blah-blah
 <%= f.submit 'Postpone' %>
 <% end %>
```

Here is the action:

```
def postponed
  @fleet = Fleet.find(params[:id])
  @fleet.update_attributes(params[:fleet])
end
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll just want this in your routes

```
match 'fleets/postponed', :id => /d+/, :via => :post, :controller => 'fleets', :action => 'postponed'
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this route `<host>/fleets/postponed?id=31` you should have the following route

```
match 'fleets/postponed/:id', :via => :post
```

Refer Routing Guide Section on [The Query Strings](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string)

```
match ':controller/:action/:id'
```

An incoming path of `/fleets/postponed/1?user_id=2` will be dispatched to the postponed action of the Fleets controller. params will be `{ :controller => “fleets”, :action => “postponed”, :id => “1”, :user_id => “2” }`.